# Prove or disprove $\forall A: A\ne \emptyset \implies \emptyset\in A$.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

A priori I would think this is a false statement because if $S:=\{1,2,3\}$ then I would say $\{\emptyset\}\notin S$ but then by analyzing the *contrapositive* of the statement, that is, $\forall A: \emptyset \notin A\implies A=\emptyset$ I think the proposition in the title would be a consequence of the [*uniqueness of the empty set*](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Empty_Set_is_Unique), wouldn't it? Meaning it is actually true that $\forall A\ne \emptyset\implies \emptyset \in A$.

Comment: your hypothesis is that A is a set, but not the empty set?

Comment: The same $S$ is still a counterexample.

Comment: Why? Would it be a consequence of the uniqueness of the empty set. I think you have a serious misunderstanding.

Comment: Remember, $\{\emptyset\}$ is not the same as $\emptyset$.

Answer (score 1):

The statement "$A\neq\emptyset$" asserts that $A$ is not empty and has at least one element, and the statement "$\emptyset\in A$" is saying that the empty set is an *element* of $A$. We want to clarify that it's false that if a set $A$ is not empty then one of its elements is the empty set. You can use the set $S:=\{1,2,3\}$ as a counterexample like previously mentioned. It is clear that $S\neq\emptyset$ because $S$ contains at least one element. Since $\emptyset$ is not an *element* of $S$, $S$ is a counterexample that disproves the statement. Be careful though with $\{\emptyset\}$ versus $\emptyset$ because they are not the same thing. A box of nothingness is not the same as nothingness itself. So even though it's true that $\{\emptyset\}\not\in S$, that doesn't have anything to do with the statement you're trying to prove or disprove. You can still use $S$ as a counterexample to prove the contrapositive false since $\emptyset\not\in S$ but $S\neq\emptyset$ because it contains at least one element. Either way, your set $S$ is a valid counterexample that disproves the statement.

Also, it is true that the empty set is unique, but all that really does is show us that if the empty set is not an element of another set, we don't have to check if other empty sets are elements since there is only one empty set that exists. And it also helps us know that if a set is not the empty set, it must have at least one element and it can't be some other type of empty set.

Comment: I know what's my misunderstanding... If a prove $0$ is the only natural number such that $n+0=n$ for any $n\in \mathbb{N}$ that doesn't mean that if a have $n+0=n$ this implies $n=0$. This is true but no because of $0$'s uniqueness, right?

Comment: Well this is vacuously true because $0\not\in\mathbb{N}$ so the premise is false.

Comment: You may be thinking of the whole numbers, $\mathbb{W}$, since $0$ is the smallest element in $\mathbb{W}$.

Comment: Remember, $\mathbb{N}=\{1,2,3,\dots\}$ and $0\not\in\mathbb{N}$.